# Disposing base class before inherited class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, dispose, idisposable

I have two classes:

```
public abstract class UnitOfWorkBase: IDisposable { }
public sealed class UnitOfWorkSql: UnitOfWorkBase { }
```

The `Dispose` method of the derived class normally looks like this:

```
protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
{
    if (!this.Disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Managed.
        }

        // Unmanaged.

        this.Disposed = true;
    }

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

I've always seen the call to `base.Dispose(disposing)` at the end of the method. However, in a recent scenario, there is a need to dispose objects of the base class before objects in the derived class as follows:

```
protected override void Dispose (bool disposing)
{
    base.Dispose(disposing);

    if (!this.Disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Managed.
        }

        // Unmanaged.

        this.Disposed = true;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is considered bad practice. Is there anything to watch out for?

Comment: I suspect you don't see this variant because it's unusual to have this requirement - could you share a little more detail on why the base class *needs* to `Dispose` first? It would tend to indicate that you have some sets of classes with unusual lifetimes or relationships.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I'll explain the context in a follow up message. In the meanwhile, do you see any general gotchas with this variant?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The `UnitOfWorkBase` class contains a generic `IDbTransaction` object while the `UnitOfWorkSql` class contains a concrete `DbContext` object. I've chosen to keep the transaction object in the base class since all foreseeable database platforms will use `IDbTransaction`. Also, I do not want to expose the actual transaction object as either `public` or `protected`. So the `UnitOfWorkSql` class is always wrapped in a `using` statement whereas the `private` transaction object needs to get disposed first. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should break the usual pattern here. Instead of:

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            //dispose my resources
        }
    }
}
```

Write something like:

```
class BaseClass
{
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            //dispose my resources
            DisposeManagedOverride();
        }

        CloseUnmanagedOverride();
    }

    protected virtual void DisposeManagedOverride() {}

    protected virtual void CloseUnmanagedOverride() {}
}
```

This way you will ensure the proper order of the resources release.